# Run job once a minute, every day, except during a certain time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I have a Sql server 2012 agent job which currently runs every minute, every day, etc.

I'd like to modify it so that it will run every minute, every day except on Saturdays between 7:00 pm and 11:30 pm. Is this possible with the job scheduler?

I tried using a daily frequency and I can change the time on a per day basis that way, but not for a specific day.

Current schedule:

[image]

Comment: I've never tried this but I think I've seen that you can have multiple schedules on a single job. If so, create one for every minute on every day except Saturdays, and possibly two more for Saturdays, 12am till 7pm and 11:30pm till 12:59pm.

Comment: Or one schedule that runs every day from 11:30pm to 06:59pm and another that runs every day except Saturday from 07:00pm to 11:29pm

Comment: Would it be possible to run a .NET application whose sole job is scheduling rather than having a Sql Server job? #Quartz

Comment: @jcolebrand Yuck. Sounds like far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I've used multiple schedules for a single job and they work, so @AndriyM's idea is pretty valid. You could give that a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can work with that single job to get that exact schedule.  You might want to consider having another job that disables/enables the job for the period of time that you don't want it to run.  Another solution would be to add another conditional logic to your existing job and do a check on the current day of the week and what time it is, and decide whether or not to execute your job's logic.

A few alternatives here, but I think you'll have to get creative with your relatively complex schedule.

Comment: Interesting. Any thoughts on @AndriyM's comment? (would that be preferable to your idea for instance)

Comment: I second conditionals within the code

Comment: Yep, that should definitely be a possibility.  Whatever solution you choose, the point is it'll have more than one dimension that we typically work with.

Comment: @jcolebrand Unfortunately this job calls an SSIS package, and the problem I'm trying to avoid is based on the SSIS package running at all, not what it's doing (the SSIS maintenance job is running into locks, more info here if you're interested: http://www.ssistalk.com/2012/07/16/ssis-2012-beware-the-ssis-server-maintenance-job/)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the hassle of creating another job which disables this job etc. To keep things simple:

```
End current schedule on Saturday 6:59:00 PM.
Create another schedule with same frequency starting on Saturday 11:00:00 PM.
```

Another way of seeing this question is:

```
How do I maintain the same frequency expect between x & y.
```

This is a common situation and the need behind this is justified for any planned maintenance. I hope MS implements a more robust schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 3 jobs as weekly, 1 set weekly for Sun-Fri 12am-11:59pm and another 2 to set weekly to run on saturday only, one for in the morning and one for after.

Answer (score 0):

I also did search answer for similar problem and found solution from here: [SQL Server Agent Job - Schedule daily except 1 day per month.](https://serverfault.com/a/122008/623548)

Solution: I did create one more TSQL step and made it the first one to run. In the new step add something like this *(change DATEPART logic as you need)*:

```
IF DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) = 7 AND CAST(GETDATE() AS time) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '23:30:00'
   EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'NAME OF THE SQL JOB HERE';
```

So what this example logic does is that if it's Saturday between 7:00 pm and 11:30 pm then it cancels the job *(it shows up in history as cancelled)*.

NB! sp_stop_job lives in msdb so choose it in step or add it to TSQL.